# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, arrays, artificial-intelligence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4QP0.png)

This is my code :

```
config = Config(mode='conv')

    if config.mode == 'conv':
        X, y = build_rand_feat()
        y_flat = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
        model=get_conv_model()

    elif config.mode == 'time':
        X, y = build_rand_feat()
        y_flat = np.argmax(y,axis=1)
        input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])
        model = get_recurrent_model()
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't do `axis=1` on data that has one dimension. You can do `axis=0` though, but we don't know what the data is or what you're expecting to happen so I can't be sure if that's what you need

Answer (score 0):

simply change to axis 0, as has only one dimension. Good Luck!